# Using a buffalo wl12-pci-g54s on Debian Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, network-adapter, static-ip

I have a buffalo wl12-pci-g54s wireless card that I want to install in my PC running Debian.  I need this so I can move the server to a better location in another room.

So, is there an easy way to do this?  Some package that I can install and get up and running?  Other instructions that I found online have been confusing.  I am also using a static IP, so I need to retain that when I make the switch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before you start using your wireless card, you need to make sure that you have the correct drivers installed. Try this first:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx.

If this works, you will be able to use your card with the stanard gui for managing wireless netoworks. Regarding static IP there are a few ways to do it. I recently started to configure the DHCP server to give a static IP for a given MAC code, this way all the configuration is in one place.